# Converted video is not played in Firefox

Tags: node.js, typescript, video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a code that accepts the video file from the client converts it and saves it on the server with `.mp4` extension. Video processing is made using `fluent-ffmpeg`. Here is the code:

```
ffmpeg(<SOURCE_FILE>)
  .size('360x?')
  .videoCodec('libx264')
  .output(<TARGET_FILE>)
  .on("end", () => {
    console.log(`Video saved with resolution 360`);
    res.json('Uploaded')
  })
  .on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(
      `Error saving video with resolution 360:`,
      error
    );
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Conversion error" });
  })
  .run();
```

The problem is that the resulting files are not played in the Firefox browser (but work in Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome).
Is it possible to change the parameters so that the resulting files are compatible with Firefox browser?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me on Firefox 115.0.2. 
However, apparently there is a [general workaround](https://gist.github.com/Vestride/278e13915894821e1d6f#support) by using `-pix_fmt yuv420p`:

```js
ffmpeg(<SOURCE_FILE>)
  .size('360x?')
  .videoCodec('libx264')
  .outputOptions('-pix_fmt yuv420p')
  .output(<TARGET_FILE>)
  // ...
```